# TeX Capacity exceeded, semantic nest size

Tags: errors, pdftex, unicode, nesting

I'm having a problem that I have no idea what it can be caused by, the error it produces is the following "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500]. \end{align}" Using TeX studio and have compiled with both PDFLatex and LuaLaTeX getting the same result.

Here's a MWE that produces the error (have included the whole preamble since adding '\usepackage{unicode-math}' to the preamble somehow solves the problem (but I don't want to use unicode math):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{bbold}
\let\dagger\dag

\begin{document}
        \begin{align}
    \ket{q,t}&=\mathcal{U}^\dag\ket{q}\\
    \ket{p,t}&=\mathcal{U}^\dag\ket{p}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

What could possibly be causing the error and how to fix it? Why does unicode math solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\let\dag\dagger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment works the other way around, you need to say `\let\dag\dagger` to have a shorthand for `\dagger`. I'd *never* do that in my documents. Imagine you share your documents with collaborators, and they'd do the same. (I also kicked out the unrelated packages.)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}

\let\dag\dagger

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \ket{q,t}&=\mathcal{U}^\dag\ket{q}\\
    \ket{p,t}&=\mathcal{U}^\dag\ket{p}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That fixed the problem completely! Thank you! However I still wonder why including unicode math made it so it didn't mind.